pointer to incomplete class type "QHeaderView" is not allowed
I have a QTableView and QStandardItemModel and I have got 3 columns. I want that one column adjusts itself when I change the size of the main window. But I get following error:

pointer to incomplete class type "QHeaderView" is not allowed

The error appears when I write this code.
QTableView* output_view = new QTableView(this);
output_view->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Strech);


just add to cpp file where you have this error: #include <QHeaderView>. This is common simple compilation error and it is result of forward declaring classes (goal is to speed up build times). You will see this error quite often (even with your own code when you use forward declarations).

This question is similar to: Pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
